# keyboard events not getting called in mountain lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsevent

I want to receive notification for any keyboard event in my application, the following code in applitionDidFinishLaunching method ,is working well on lion but its not getting called on mountain lion.

```
 [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {

NSLog(@"key pressed");        
    }];
```

I am getting mouse moved event but not working for keyboard events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to receive  key down events globally, then you must set following settings in your mac:

**System Preferences** --->  **Accessibility** -->
and check the **Enable access for assistive devices** (atleast for keyboard)

then your system can receive key down events globally.

Comment: I can't see this option! I'm on 10.9.